# SQL query to get only the latest value by Date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following two tables:

Table1 {T1ID, Name}

Table2 {T2ID, T1ID, Date, Value}

Date is of type DATE.

and I am looking for a SQL query to fetch *only the latest value (by Date)* for each T1ID for which the Name matches a specific string.

```
SELECT`Table2`.`T1ID`,
    `Table2`.`Value`,
    `Table2`.`Date`, 
    `Table1`.`Name`,
    FROM `Table1` 
    INNER JOIN `Table2` ON `Table2`.`T1ID` = `Table1`.`T1ID`
    WHERE `Table1`.`Name` LIKE 'Smith'
```

but this returns the value for several dates for the same T1ID.

How do I get only the latest value by Date?

---

Edit:
I am using MySQL 5.5.8

Comment: Please tag RDBMS though I assume it must be MySQL

Comment: What database server are you using?

Comment: @Martin Yes: MySQL 5.5.8

Comment: @tuscon I've updated my solution below to handle your question. Cheers

Comment: @tuscon So, any luck with the answers?

Comment: @Adriano I found a workaround that was actually a better solution for me (I created a new field in a table to record the latest value, and have an "archive" table for the dated values). And then I did not take the time to test your proposed solutions in more depth. Sorry about this, but I couldn't accept without testing...

Answer (score 1):

If I've understodd the question correctly:
Assuming MySQL:

```
SELECT`Table2`.`T1ID`,
`Table2`.`Value`,
`Table2`.`Date`, 
`Table1`.`Name`
FROM `Table1` 
INNER JOIN `Table2` ON `Table2`.`T1ID` = `Table1`.`ID`,
(SELECT T1ID, MAX(Date) AS 'Date' FROM Table2 GROUP BY T1ID) Table3
WHERE 
`Table3`.`T1ID` = `Table2`.`T1ID`
AND
`Table3`.`Date` = `Table2`.`Date`
AND
`Table1`.`Name` LIKE 'Smith'
```

**EDIT: Updated the code to bring back the correct result set. Removed MSSQL answer as it wasn't relevant**

Comment: The OP wants the lastest per group, not over all groups.

Comment: @Martin Ah, my bad - I mis-read the question. I've updated the solution to handle that.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.

```
select t1.t1id, max(t1.Name) Name, max(t2.date) Date, 
(select Value from table2 t22 
 where t22.date = max(t2.date) and t22.t1id = t2.t1id) Value
from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on t1.t1id = t2.t1id
where Name like '%Smith%'
group by t2.t1id order by 2
```

OR

```
select mx.t1id, mx.Name, mx.Date, t2.Value
from 
(
select t1.t1id, max(t1.Name) Name, max(t2.date) Date
from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on t1.t1id = t2.t1id
where Name like '%Smith%'
group by t2.t1id
) mx left join table2 t2 on (t2.t1id = mx.t1id and t2.date = mx.date)
order by 2
```

Both will produce the same result. The first one takes less code but you might have performance issues with a huge set of data. The second one takes a little more code, but it is also a little more optimized. Notes on the **JOIN** option:

- If you go LEFT JOIN (as the example shows), items in Table1 with no correspondent records on Table2 **will be displayed** in the result, but the values in columns Date and Value will be NULL
- If you go INNER JOIN, items in Table1 with no correspondent records on Table2 **will not be displayed**.

**EDIT**

I missed one of the requirements, which was the Name matching a specific string. The code is now updated. The '%' acts like a wildcard, so it will match names like 'Will Smith' and 'Wail Smithers'. If you want a exact match, remove the wildcards ('%').

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your SQL:

```
ORDER BY 'Date' DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: The OP wants the lastest per group ("for each T1ID "), not over all groups.